# Why is cumsum not working with symbolic vectors?

Tags: octave, symbolic-math, cumsum

I wrote a small Octave script involving `cumsum` on symbolic vectors, which I expected to work but unfortunately, it does not.
Here's the code:

```
pkg load symbolic
n = 3;
syms q x
q = sym('q', [n 1]);
x = sym('x', [n 1]);
cumsum(q - x)
```

Instead of the expected result, I get:

> error: cumsum: wrong type argument 'class'

Why does this happen? Would it work with Matlab Symbolic Toolbox? (I don't have it so I cannot test, unfortunately.)

Comment: This works in MATLAB with the symbolic toolbox, outputting `[q1 - x1; q1 + q2 - x1 - x2; q1 + q2 + q3 - x1 - x2 - x3]` as you'd expect

Comment: Works with MATLAB Online. So, I guess, it'll work with MATLAB as well.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this issue up. I have added basic cumsum and cumprod functions as a merge request on the [project page] (https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/symbolic/merge-requests/).

Comment: Update: https://github.com/cbm755/octsympy/pull/1034

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just because `cumsum` written in Octave is not supported for symbolic elements as indicated by the error message. Your code gives the following in MATLAB:

```
ans =
                     q1 - x1
           q1 + q2 - x1 - x2
 q1 + q2 + q3 - x1 - x2 - x3
```

---

You can do something like this:

```
t1 = q-x;
t2 = triu(ones(numel(t1)));
sum(repmat(t1,1,3).*t2).'
% repmat is necessary here because implicit expansion is also not 
% supported for matrices of class sym in Octave
```

Above code in Octave and MATLAB gives the following respectively:

```
ans = (sym 3×1 matrix)

  ⎡            q₁₁ - x₁₁            ⎤
  ⎢                                 ⎥
  ⎢      q₁₁ + q₂₁ - x₁₁ - x₂₁      ⎥
  ⎢                                 ⎥
  ⎣q₁₁ + q₂₁ + q₃₁ - x₁₁ - x₂₁ - x₃₁⎦
```

```
ans =
                     q1 - x1
           q1 + q2 - x1 - x2
 q1 + q2 + q3 - x1 - x2 - x3
```

Comment: Nice answer. I wonder though, would implementing cumsum as a for loop necessarily be much slower than performing it as a matrix calculation when it comes to symbolic math?

Comment: What also works is: `for i = 1:n; b(i) = sum(q(1:i)) - sum(x(1:i)); end` or even shorter: `A = tril(ones(n)); A*(q - x)`
Actually, I already had the `tril` version as a matrix multiplication, but then I found an error in the (numeric) `cumsum` variant and corrected it. Later, I also wanted to correct the left-hand-side matrix `A`, so that both variants would give the same result. Now they do. :)

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of stating the obvious, this can be impemented as a for loop.
Here is one implementation.

```
function Y = cumsum( X, N )
    if nargin < 2, N = 1; end
    YDims = size( X );  NDim = YDims(N); Y = sym( zeros( YDims ) );
    XIdx = substruct( '()', repmat( {':'}, 1, ndims( X ) ) );
    YIdx = substruct( '()', repmat( {':'}, 1, ndims( Y ) ) );
    for i = 1 : NDim
        XIdx.subs{N} = 1 : i;
        YIdx.subs{N} = i;
        Y = subsasgn( Y,
                      YIdx,
                      sum( subsref( X, XIdx ), N )
                    );
    end
end
```

Copy this in your symbolic installation folder<sup>1</sup> as cumsum.m and your above script will work as in matlab.

---

<sub>1: (in my case this was ~/.octave/symbolic-2.9.0/@sym/cumsum.m because I have set my pkg prefix as ~/.octave )</sub>